# du summary isn't equal to sum of the elements

Tags: filesize, du

The directory contains normal files in normal directories, no symlinks and remote fs (it's actually a maildir++ storage, so not even sparse files are expected). I don't readily see how it's possible that the summary of the directory sizes is **significantly** larger than the total `du` provides:

```
$ du * .[a-zA-Z]* -bsc | tail -n1
2722800257      total

$ du * .[a-zA-Z]* -b | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
3341577554
```

Reality seems to match the larger number.

Comment: Okay, all I wrote was true _except_ I properly did *not* mention that there are no **hardlinks**, which was lucky because it turned out that there **were** hardlinks. *du* seems to carefully resolve hardlinks internally so counting dirs _individually_ gives a much larger number than by once, since hardlinked files are counted multiple times. *du* acts weird though since counts those always at the **first** occurence, so **the order of args actually does matter** if you care about *some* of the directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second command `du -b ... | awk ...` is overstating the total because it counts subdirectory sizes multiple times.  Each subdirectory size is counted on its own, then counted again as part of the size of each of its ancestor directories.

It's easier to see what's happening in a small example like this, on a filesystem where an empty directory happens to consume 4KB:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/bar/baz

$ du -bsc foo
12288   foo
12288   total

$ du -b foo
4096    foo/bar/baz
8192    foo/bar
12288   foo

$ du -b foo | awk '{t += $1} END {print t}'
24576
```